# How to get <image> src php with javascript popup function to display in html

Tags: php

How to get  src php with javascript popup function to display in html.
My question is how to apply php for display javascript in HTML tag.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$response_data = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
$load_string = simplexml_load_string($response_data);
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td width='30' align='center'>".$row['id']."</td>";
echo '<td><img src='.$load_string->channel->item[0]->image.'></a></td>';
```

$load_string->channel->item[0]->image is converting tag to http://www.google.com/sample.jpg.

but i don't know how to apply javascript popup function because apostrophe ' and " grammer.

Javascript popup function example

```
echo '<td><a href="logo.gif" onclick=window.open(this.href,'"_blank"'.'.'width=300px,height=300px,toolbars=no,scrollbars=no'.'); return false;><img src="logo.gif"></a></td>';
```

i need to modify php grammer, but i can't convert and apply php grammer error for ' " .
echo 'channel->item[0]->image." onclick=window.open(this.href,'"_blank"'.'.'width=300px,height=300px,toolbars=no,scrollbars=no'.'); return false;>';

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$response_data = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
$load_string = simplexml_load_string($response_data);
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td width='30' align='center'>".$row['id']."</td>";
echo '<td><a href=".$load_string->channel->item[0]->image." onclick=window.open(this.href,'"_blank"'.'.'width=300px,height=300px,toolbars=no,scrollbars=no'.'); return false;><img src="logo.gif"></a></td>';
```

help me.

Comment: You should write"<?php $row['id']?> "instead of  ".$row['id']. " and all other php variables like this.

Comment: thank you for your comment. i have fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape your simple quotes inside a string with the "\" character.

```
echo '<td><a href="'.$load_string->channel->item[0]->image.'" onclick="window.open(this.href,\'_blank\',\'width=300px,height=300px,toolbars=no,scrollbars=no\'); return false;"><img src="logo.gif"></a></td>';
```

Comment: thank you. your reply is right. i apply web immediately

Answer (score -1):

```
<img src="logo.gif" id="imageLogo">

var imageSrc = document.getElementById("imageLogo").src;
```

Comment: thank you for reply. i will try to apply your script .